# How to clean a BigQuery table by removing duplicates based on 2 of 8 columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a google `BigQuery` table with columns `col_1_id`, `col_2_id`, `col_3`, `col_4`, `col_5`, `col_6`, `col_7`, `col_8`

The issue is that there are many rows that have the identical `col_1_id` and `col_2_id` and which I have to make unique. I have tried to GROUP BY the table based on the two columns and then select the first, but that takes too much memory.

How can I clean the table so that there are no two rows with identical `col_1_id`, `col_2_id`?

This is what I tried and failed with:

```
SELECT
  col_1_id,
  col_2_id,
  ANY_VALUE(col_3), 
  ANY_VALUE(col_4),
  ANY_VALUE(col_5),
  ANY_VALUE(col_6),
  ANY_VALUE(col_7),
  ANY_VALUE(col_8)
FROM
  `my_proj.my_table` A
GROUP BY
  A.col_1_id,
  A.col_2_id
```

but I get a message like:

> Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. GROUP BY operator used too much memory

and also I'm not sure how this would delete the rows.

How can I have a query that either removes the duplicates in-place or creates a new table with the results?

Comment: My first thought is to use a higher billing tier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to recreate table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tab_name
AS
SELECT * EXCEPT rn
FROM(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col_1_id,col_2_id ORDER BY 1) AS rn
     FROM tab_name) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

After that drop old table and rename.

---

EDIT:

Using [QUALIFY clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab_name AS
SELECT *
FROM tab_name
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col_1_id,col_2_id ORDER BY 1) = 1;
```

Comment: I would be *very* surprised if `row_number()` would work where `group by` failed in BQ.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Let's the user1367204 give a try :)

Comment: @lad2025 . . . I find it interesting.  I haven't found that `row_number()` works for me to fix this problem in BQ.